# How do I get started with JavaScriptMVC?

Tags: javascript, javascript-framework, javascriptmvc

Are there any good resources to get started with JavaScriptMVC? Resources like tutorials, blogs or books?

This is what I have found so far

- https://gist.github.com/989117
- http://javascriptmvc.com/docs/getstarted.html#
- http://wiki.javascriptmvc.com/wiki/index.php?title=Getting_Started

Thanks for you help

Comment: Sounds like you know more than I do about tutorials. Are they insufficient? Is there something you don't understand?

Comment: @Jared, I am looking for a resource which explain all the concepts in JavaScriptMVC with a sample project.

Answer (score 1):

I'm working on that as well. Addy Osmani (Javascript developer for AOL, works on the jQuery team) recommended the book JavaScript Web Applications by Alex McCaw to me on Google+.

http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920018421.do

I'm only a 50-60 pages into it so far but it is based off of the MVC approach.

Comment: I worked on the book, so it's a good start.  But the new docs have a lot of walkthroughs and tutorials.